do_populate_sdk fails because of libpython3.6m.so.1.0
I've run bitbake to build my custom image with no error. But then have an error for running populate_sdk.
I'm using kirkstone branch for both poky and qt5 layers.
Error Log:
ERROR: custom-image-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/sdk/image --setopt=logdir=/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo --nogpgcheck install nativesdk-binutils nativesdk-cpp-symlinks nativesdk-dtc nativesdk-fiptool-stm32mp nativesdk-flex nativesdk-gcc-arm-none-eabi nativesdk-gcc-symlinks nativesdk-glibc-gconv-utf-16 nativesdk-glibc-gconv-utf-32 nativesdk-libyaml nativesdk-libyaml-dev nativesdk-ncurses-libncursesw nativesdk-openocd-stm32mp nativesdk-openssl-dev nativesdk-optee-sdk nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host nativesdk-perl-module-encode nativesdk-perl-module-encode-encoding nativesdk-perl-module-encode-mime-header nativesdk-perl-module-file-spec-functions nativesdk-perl-module-integer nativesdk-perl-module-pod-text nativesdk-perl-module-term-ansicolor nativesdk-python3-cffi nativesdk-python3-cryptography nativesdk-python3-dev nativesdk-python3-pillow nativesdk-python3-pycparser nativesdk-python3-pycryptodomex nativesdk-python3-pyelftools nativesdk-python3-setuptools nativesdk-sdcard-raw-tools nativesdk-stm32wrapper4dbg nativesdk-svd-tools nativesdk-swig nativesdk-u-boot-mkimage nativesdk-wayland packagegroup-cross-canadian-stm32mp15-disco' returned 1:DNF version: 4.11.1cachedir: /home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/sdk/image/var/cache/dnfAdded oe-repo repo from /home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repoUser-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (Ubuntu 20.04; generic; Linux.x86_64)'repo: using cache for: oe-repooe-repo: using metadata from Sat 08 Jun 2024 11:40:09 AM UTC.Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sat 08 Jun 2024 11:58:17 AM UTC.--> Starting dependency resolution--> Finished dependency resolutionError:Problem: conflicting requests

nothing provides libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by nativesdk-gcc-arm-none-eabi-11-r0.x86_64_nativesdk(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp15_disco-oe-linux-gnueabi/custom-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.3776069ERROR: Task (/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/../layers/meta-app/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb:do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4916 tasks of which 4915 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:/home/anh/stm32mp1-yocto/build/../layers/meta-app/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb:do_populate_sdkSummary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.`

I have try to install libpython3.6-dev using apt-get. The files can be found under /usr/lib/x86_64-gnu/ but i still can't get over this error.
Any ideas how to fix the problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

I ran bitbake to create a sdk with a default local.conf file and change only some of the configurations. After deleting all unnecessary configurations, and then rerun bitbake. It works.

If your host computer is running Ubuntu, you have to change the variable PACKAGE_CLASSES in local.conf from package_rpm to package_deb to match your current system..
#PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"

PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"

